# Swift - trouble with accessing mapView from another class

Tags: ios, swift, mkmapview, viewcontroller

I'd like to set location on map by the button which belongs to cell in tableView. The thing is, how to get the current instant of my ViewController instead of creating a new one? The method in my CustomCell is as follows:

```
@IBAction func mapButton(sender: AnyObject) {
        ViewController().showPinOnMap(Location)
    }
}
```

I end up with mapView equal to nil, I guess because I instatiate new ViewContoller instead of getting access to one that already exists.
I've read about Type Methods, but I'm not sure how to deal with them. In my ViewController I tried:

```
class func showPinOnMap(location: CLLocationCoordinate2D?){
    if(location != nil){
        map.setCenterCoordinate(location!, animated: true)
    }
}
```

but it results with the following error
[image]

I guess the whole thing is about accessing ViewController instance instead of created a brand new one(correct me if I'm wrong).

I'd appreciate any help, thanks in advance

Comment: this happens because you use `map` an instance variable in `class` method

Comment: How to fix it? delete "class" and stop usyng type method and look for different approach?

Comment: answer depends to app architecture, but if you like to use only one instance of ViewController try to implement singletone or create instance each time of mapButton pressed

Comment: but creating instance each time button is pressed  ( ViewController().showPinOnMap(Location) ) led to me to runtime error because map is equal to nil in that case

Comment: Yes, in class method, you should create property, set location to it and read value on viewDidLoad

Comment: I'm afraid I don't get it...location is passed and set properly, the problem is that mere mapView called here "map" is nil

Comment: OK, lets try to help you with right direction). Show you code, where you define `map`, and where you initialize it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not calling an actual instance of your `ViewController` but the class itself. `map` however is a member of an instance of `ViewController`. To solve this, you have to call `map` on the respective instance.

This can be done by a callback for instance. E.g. in `CustomCell` define a variable:

```
var onMapButtonCallback : ((CLLocationCoordinate2D) -> Void)?
```

which you then can execute from `mapButton`:

```
@IBAction func mapButton(sender: AnyObject) {
    onMapButtonCallback?(Location)
}
```

The thing left to do is connecting the callback in `ViewController`, which, I assume, instantiates also `CustomCell`:

```
customCell.onMapButtonCallback = { location in self.showPinOnMap(location) }
```

Comment: Wow, amazing hack! It works perfectly but I guess it'll take me a while to fully comprehend this solution! Thanks!

Comment: I would not call it a hack. It is a common pattern.

Comment: For iOS rookie stuff like that looks like hack:) You mean this is a common pattern to call functions from another classes? Or generally?

Comment: It is one pattern to make communication between separated classes happen. Another one is to make a delegate. Or you could also use `NSNotification`.